# How to receive images from a form in a bidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a form for uploading products, a user can upload more than 1 product, and each product can have many pictures (max 6)

Example:
Product 0 = image 1, image 2, image 3.
Product 1 = image 1, image 2.
This is how it would look like in array form:

```
Images[0][0] = image 1
Images[0][1] = image 2
Images[0][2] = image 3
Images[1][0] = image 1
Images[1][1] = image 2
```

The problem with this is that I don't receive a bidimensional array from the form, I think I'm receiveing a single array with N amount of images, like this

```
Images[0]
Images[1]
Images[2]
Images[3]
Images[4]
```

Which makes impossible to assign the images to the products.
I'm receiving the images with `$_FILES['photo']['name']` and looping through the array

The form that sends images is this

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="photo" name="photo[]" onchange="return fileValidation()" value="Photo" multiple="multiple" required/>
```

I don't know if I need to add name="photo[][]" or something similar

Actually uploading the images is not the problem, that part works fine, the problem comes later, when we need to add each image to their corresponding product, and if we receive a bunch of images in a single array it will be impossible to know how many images were sent to each product.

Comment: Do you have only one file input? how do you expect it to distinguish which product the image belong to? Or do you have multiple file inputs?

Comment: I have many inputs, with a Js function I add more inputs and so the image input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps use a subscript to associate the image sets with each product:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" name="product[0][image][]" ...>
    <input type="file" name="product[1][image][]" ...>
</form>
```

Then you can loop through the image sets with:

```
foreach ($_FILES['product']['image'] as $k => $v) {
    foreach ($v['name'] as $name) {
        echo "Processing item $name in image set $k";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. I receive Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in $v['name'] , I don't know if the index 'name' for v does not exist.

Comment: Hi, perhaps try `print_r($FILES)` to see the structure.

Comment: I mean the problem is not printing the names, it's in the second foreach when I try to loop $v['name']

Comment: at the end it worked by simply adding an extra index to input. <input type="file" name="product[0][]" ...> Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When upload files, PHP `$_FILES` is not an array of file, but an array like,

```
Array(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => facepalm2.jpg
            [1] => facepalm3.jpg
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => image/jpeg
            [1] => image/jpeg
        )
        ...
)
```

You should access it like,

```
foreach($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"] as $index => $temp_name){
    echo $_FILES["photo"]["name"][$index];
    echo $_FILES["photo"]["size"][$index];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I have this bunch of images per indexes, for example$_FILES["photo"]["name"][$index]; of product 1 and then $_FILES["photo"]["name"][$index]; of product 2.

Comment: @OscarVazquez refer to https://www.php.net/manual/zh/reserved.variables.files.php#121618